Can we create a Single Model on multiple Time series data that captures on/off state of sensors?
I have 5 input and 1 output column
input columns : Time, state, power, rpm, temp
output column : output
Time is measured in seconds.
state can be 0 or 1 indicating on/off.
power, rpm, temp values are set constant.
Once all the values are set, the system will generate output from 0th second to nth second.
Given another set of values for power, rpm, temp, the system will generate another output.
Meanwhile when generating the output, the machine can be turned on/off at regular intervals.
Graph output will go up and down based on state.
Based on different values set for power, rpm, temp, I'm collecting output data in different sheets.
I have 5 sheets of data each is a different time series data starting from 0 to nth second.
One sheet Data looks like this:



Time
state
power
rpm
temp
output




0
1
225
0.3
40
0.0566


1
1
225
0.3
40
0.0544


2
1
225
0.3
40
0.0542


3
0
225
0.3
40
0.0547


4
0
225
0.3
40
0.0555



And similar kind of data will be in another sheet with different values of power, rpm, temp, output.
I'm able to create separate deep learning model that can predict output based on input for each sheet.
But, My LSTM model is not able to capture the on/off details in "state" column. Which means, graph goes in opposite direction when it is off and vice versa.
Output graph link
Here blue --> Actual and Red --> predicted. Graph should go down when state=0 and should go up when state=1. As we can see from the image, the actual graph goes up when state=1, but predicted graph goes down and up.
Is there any way I can predict by combining all sheets using a single ML/DL model without overfitting ?

Alright so here's the deal; If you have combined N sheets and then applied scaling/normalization on the resultant merged new sheet, then it will distort the actual time series distribution of the original sheets.
Here's an example:
Sheet 1 (Time: 0.....10)
Sheet 2 (Time: 0....20)
Sheet 3 (Time: 0....100)
Now if you apply scaling on the resultant merged sheets, it will have a resultant scaled time values of 0-100, in which the entire time series distribution of the original sheets is distorted, and hence their sequential values are completely unordered. This way, the model doesn't learn the co-relation of features (state) and their impact on output label.
Solution: Why not individually scale each sheet separately, and then combine the resultant scaled sheets and train model on it, then apply inverse transformation before prediction. I hope it helps.

Thanks for the thought. But I have one doubt. Say I have 4 sheets of training data scaled separately and I have 4 separate scaler object used to prepare training data.  I want to test it with 5th sheet. Model output will be scaled. Which scaler object will I use for inverse transform operation as different sheet output could be in different range based on input parameters ?

The sheet which has closest start and stop time sequence values can be used as the scaler object for inverse transform operation of the 5th sheet
